# How to create PNG thumbnail if "imagecreatefrompng()" fails?

Tags: php, png, thumbnails, imagecreatefrompng

I start to create a PNG thumbnail by using this function:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("http://imagenic.net/images/pfujz9j5juav1qrex00.png");
```

However, it says:

```
'http://imagenic.net/images/pfujz9j5juav1qrex00.png' is not a valid PNG file
```

It works OK with other PNG images, so I guess something is wrong with this specific picture.

What can I do in this situation ?

Is there another way to create the thumbnail ?

(BTW, I found this picture in the web.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using getimagesize() returns a mime value of image/jpeg, you can call this function to determine which imagecreatefrom... function to call next.

Answer (score 4):

According to Firefox, that image is actually a JPEG image. Someone's just given it the wrong extension. You can use the [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function to check the actual type of the file by sniffing it's header.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the other `imagecreatefrom*()` functions. Or use the [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) functions and stop guessing.